# Convert List<Boolean> to byte [ ] array

Tags: java, android, arrays, type-conversion, boolean-logic

I have a list of booleans which I want to convert Byte [] arrays.I try to convert List to byte[] arrays but I have a mistake.This is my code

```
 List<Boolean> list = model.getBooleanData();
               boolean[] inputSleep = new boolean[list.size()];

               byte[] toReturn = new byte[inputSleep.length / 8];
               for (int entry = 0; entry < toReturn.length; entry++) {
                   for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++) {
                       if (inputSleep[entry * 8 + bit]) {
                           toReturn[entry] |= (128 >> bit);
                       }
                   }
               }
```

I get all Booleans and checked but I try to this all Booleans false.Thanks your helps.How can I correctly convert List to byte[] arrays?

Comment: `boolean[] inputSleep` - all values are initialised to `false` - you never fill the array with your boolean data from `list`. Have `model.getBooleanData()` return a `boolean[]` directly - the `List` is pointless.

Comment: But I fill List from model and checked the model is filled to booleans.And than I checked inputSleep all values False.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, and the reason why?

Comment: Can you be sure that 8 divides into the list length? Otherwise list elements will be lost.

Comment: Ooo sorry man,I understand now If I set the inputSleep from List Booleans all inputsleep values not to be false.I'll try )

Comment: @OleV.V. yeap I'm sure

Comment: your **meaningful** data is in the "list", but you are processing the boolean array (with default values of false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeap thank you guys I solved the problem.
This is the right code. Maybe this solution needs someone)

```
 List<Boolean> list = model.getBooleanData();
               Boolean[] inputSleep = new Boolean[list.size()];
               inputSleep = list.toArray(inputSleep);


               byte[] toReturn = new byte[inputSleep.length / 8];
               for (int entry = 0; entry < toReturn.length; entry++) {
                   for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++) {
                       if (inputSleep[entry * 8 + bit]) {
                           toReturn[entry] |= (128 >> bit);
                       }
                   }
               }
```